# Error while posting app request in Facebook using app login

Tags: facebook, apprequests

I am trying to post an apprequest to a user using the URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/apprequests?message=’This is a new message from the pgm’&data='t1t2t3t4’&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_RECEIVED_FROM_FB&method=post
```

I am getting the following error:

> Response Message Bad Request Response Code 400 App Request ID: 400 Bad Request
>
> Method Not Implemented
> Invalid method in request

Note: I got the access token and the same url works fine in the browser (Chrome).

Am I missing something? Couldn't find much in the documentation!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to url-encode your parameters. The browser does this transparently to you, that's why it's working there. Assuming you're using php:

```
http_build_query(array(
  "message"      => "This is a new message from the pgm",
  "data"         => "t1t2t3t4",
  "access_token" => ACCESS_TOKEN_RECEIVED_FROM_FB,
  "method"       => "post"
));
```

This will take care of the encoding and joining parameters via amperstand characters. The return value is:

```
message=This+is+a+new+message+from+the+pgm&data=t1t2t3t4&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_RECEIVED_FROM_FB&method=post
```